# Cannot serialize an object. Jackson crashes with a JsonMappingException

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, jackson

This is my code:

```
  try {

        String route = mItems.get(position);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        String tripString = mapper.writeValueAsString(tempTrip);
        Intent i = new Intent(activity, PSRouteDetailsActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("route", route);
        i.putExtra("trip", tripString);
        i.putExtra("address", address);
        if (null != completedTripDepartureTime) {
            i.putExtra("completedTripDepartureTime", completedTripDepartureTime);
        } else if (mustChooseDepartureTime) {
            i.putExtra("mustChooseDepartureTime", true);
        }
        if (checkout) {
            i.putExtra(PSRouteDetailsActivity.SHOULD_CHECKOUT_EXTRA_KEY, true);
        }
        activity.startActivity(i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Utils.appendLog("pressed on details Container" + e.getMessage(), "E", Constants.PLANNER);
    }
```

tempTrip is a `PSTrip` object. that I create empty, and then add the needed data inside.
The crash is this:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contentEquals(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference (through reference chain: nl.hgrams.passenger.model.trip.PSTrip["active"])
```

And happens when I try to create the String from the object, 3rd line from this:

```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        String tripString = mapper.writeValueAsString(tempTrip);
```

Why is this happening? I already set not to include the NULL objects

This is how my PSTrip object looks (without the methods and getter setters)

```
 @RealmClass
public class PSTrip extends RealmObject implements Serializable {

private static String TAG = PSTrip.class.getName();

private int update_interval;
private String travel_mode;
@PrimaryKey
private String id;
private String icon;
private String status;
private String notes;
private Destination destination;
private Destination origin;
private Long departure_time, arrival_time;
private Route route;
private Owner_data owner;
private String vehicle;
private Flight flight;
private double last_updated;
private MileageExpenses mileage_expenses;
private RealmList<TripStep> steps;
private RealmList<TripStop> pendingTripStops = new RealmList<>();
private RealmList<Tag> tags = new RealmList<>();
private RealmList<RealmInt> usedVehicles = new RealmList<>();
private Planned_Route planned_route;
private Group group;
private Stats stats;
private String icon_small;
private Integer revised;
private double avgspeed;
private float delay;
private boolean deleted = false;

public final static String STATUS_ACTIVE = "active";
public final static String STATUS_COMPLETED = "completed";
public static boolean isCheckingOut = false, isAddingPitstop = false, isUpdatingLocation = false, isAborting = false;
public static Float kPSMinRoundTripLength = 250f, kPSInterPitStopDistance = 150f, kPSMinDistanceCheckout = 100f;
public static Long kPSLongTimeForCheckout = 900l, kPSShortTimeForCheckout = 300l;
public static final Double kPSminTripLength = 100d;
public static final int kPSFrequentCheckoutPlace = 5;

public static double minDistanceToDestination = 999999999;
}
```

Comment: All non primitive objects are serializable? For example, the Destination class implements the Serialize interface?

Comment: yes, all objects from my objects implement Serializable

Comment: Also, I want and need the object not to be full. This is not a object that is taken from the DB or API but a temporary locally created object, that I need to send from 1 activity to another.

Comment: Can you put the full stacktrace? To see exactly where the error occured.

Comment: @rosualin if you need to send from one activity to another you should be using Parceable, it has a better performance than json. You should give it a try

Comment: ok, thanks, I'm going to look into it